# IntentService show null value

Tags: android

i tried many time but cannot get any good result.

i created IntentService in which read the accelrometer data.
but unfortunatly i got the null value.

the following is the manifest file;

```
              <uses-feature  android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="false"/>
            <service android:name=".MyIntentSericee"
        android:exported="false">

    </service>

    <activity android:name=".About"></activity>
```

And this is the java class;

```
public class MyIntentSericee extends IntentService
                    implements SensorEventListener {       
           final static String TAG = " com.example.prince.life_activity";
       StringBuilder sb;
      float x, y;
     double z;
      private Handler handler;
      private SensorManager sensor;
      private boolean mIsServiceStarted = false;
    final int intervalTime = 10000; // 10 sec
    SensorEvent event;

     public MyIntentSericee() {
    super("service");
   }


     @Override
     public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    sensor = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer = sensor.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sensor.registerListener(this, accelerometer,
               SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);        


    sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(x).toString();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),sb,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    return START_NOT_STICKY;

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    synchronized (this)
    {
        try
        {
            int count=0;
            while(count<5) {
                sb.append("" + x).toString();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), sb, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                wait(10000);
                count++;
                sensor.unregisterListener(this);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          //sensor.unregisterListener(this);
        }
    }
    }


      @Override
   public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();


         }


           @Override
       public void onSensorChanged(final SensorEvent event) {


        sensro();


          }
         @Override
       public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

      }
    public boolean isServiceStarted()
      {
    return mIsServiceStarted;
}

    public  void sensro()
    {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {


            x = event.values[0];
            y = event.values[1];
            z = event.values[2] - 9.8;

        }
    }
     }
```

any one can help to show the accelerometer values i mean to hold the accelerometer values for 10 second and then unregister the accelerometer.
and to pass these values which store ,hold for 10 second to other activity.

Answer (score 0):

onSensorChanged should set your 'event' variable with the new value received in parameter.

You work with an instance variable but you never initialize it.

I would change the sensro methods to take the event as parameter to remote that instance parameter that doesn't really have sense. You have too much attributs...

Comment: ok and how to hold the accelerometer values for some time and then unregister the accelerometer.i mean i want to campare the x values for example the x values is 2 so i campare that if the value of x>2 show something...

Comment: By keeping the last float[] values in memory, just the array, no need to keep the sensorevent or each values separatly. To unregister your service, sensor.unregisterService(this) should do it, only need to write the condition to execute this code.